# Python : How do you merge Python classes?

Tags: python

After many fail attempts I found fbs module tutorial for building python desktop app on github. It provided a sample script and how to integrate the script with fbs module.

How do you merge class from Sample App into My code ?

Sample App code :

```
from fbs_runtime.application_context import ApplicationContext, \
    cached_property
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class AppContext(ApplicationContext):
    def run(self):
        self.main_window.show()
        return self.app.exec_()
    @cached_property
    def main_window(self):
        result = QMainWindow()
        result.setWindowTitle('Hello World!')
        result.resize(250, 150)
        return result
```

My code :

```
    from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMessageBox, QAction, QPlainTextEdit, QPushButton

class Ui_Form(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

        def setupUi(self, Form):
            Form.setObjectName("Form")
            Form.resize(846, 794)

            self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            Form.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

            self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.central_widget)
            self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
       ......


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys

        # ~ app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        # ~ Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        # ~ ui = Ui_Form()
        # ~ ui.setupUi(Form)
        # ~ Form.show()
        # ~ sys.exit(app.exec_())
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        win = Ui_Form()
        app.exec_()
```

FBS repo : https://github.com/mherrmann/fbs-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

**Merge Classes? can you elaborate more?**

If you want to use class from Sample App you can extends it

```
class AppContext(ApplicationContext):
    ...

class MyNewClass(AppContext):
    # All atributes from AppContext will be in your MyNewClass
```

*EDIT**
After reading the docs from github about this project, you just need implement **class AppContext** because in this example he already inherit from external class from lib **ApplicationContext**

from fbs_runtime.application_context import ApplicationContext, \
    cached_property
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

```
class AppContext(ApplicationContext):
        ...

    def run(self):
        # Here you can change or add your own logic
        self.main_window.show()
        return self.app.exec_()

    @cached_property
    def main_window(self):
        # Here you can change or add your own logic
        result = QMainWindow() # Probabily you should manipulate this instance adding whatever you want following lib docs at github
        result.setWindowTitle('Hello World!')
        result.resize(250, 150)
        return result
```

Comment: You mean write class MyNewClass(AppContext): into My code ?

what should I put inside this class ?

Sorry, bit confuse.

Comment: Im trying to understand what you need too haha, my suggestion was you create your "NewClass" in your code and extends the Class you want (importing from external lib) so that way all atributes and methods from that class will be inherited to your "NewClass"

Please explain with more details what exacly you need

Comment: Reading the docs from url u provided, the AppContext(ApplicationContext) already do that i said above... so you just put ur logic inside that class because ApplicationContext is the external from the lib, so just implement this class what anything you want

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to do @Diego Vinicius.

should I just copy past class Ui_Form(QtWidgets.QMainWindow): into class AppContext(ApplicationContext): ?

what should modify to make them work ?

Comment: You should use the lib as external dependency and implement on top of it... Ui_Form is from ur code right?